# Обработка текстовых файлов

Tags: java, файлы

Есть задача по обработке и преобразованию файлов. Все файлы представляют собой аналог CSV(текст с разделителями)

1. дано два или более файлов. Необходимо "склеить" их по некоторым полям и выдать уже один, обработанный файл
2. дан один файл. Необходимо выполнить преобразование полей, склейку из нескольких строк в одну и т.д. и тоже выдать один, обработанный файл.

Проблема в том, что единой структуры файлов нет. Т.е. файлы/пары файлов могут быть различны по полям/структуре

На данный момент идея по такой обработке таких файлов только одна:

1. Грузим файл/файлы в некую БД(in-memory, к примеру), предварительно в runtime прочитав структуру файла - создаем таблицы по структуре
2. Выполняем некий SQL скрипт, на основании результатов которого формируем выходной файл

**Вопрос:** может есть какие-то наработанные алгоритмы/библиотеки по подобному преобразованию/обработке, чтобы не городить "велосипед"?

**UPD**: чтобы избежать привязки к структуре, конечно можно использовать некую NoSql, но тогда лишимся полноценной силы SQL

Comment: Тут-же напрашивается вопрос:А зачем БД?Краткосрочное хранение в классе сущности почему не подойдет...и анализ местного значения?

Comment: БД только как вариант. Чтобы использовать SQL для формирования конечного файла. А не перебирать массу Map интерфейсов по N-раз. Файлы могут быть большого размера(~1млн строк)

Comment: Ну для справки БД то же не магией делает такие операции...Учитывая что структура таблицы вам не известна вы будете скорее всего все с полями переменной длинны(не зная длинны каждой ячейки) ну или так же проводить доп анализ каждой строки на размер...+проверка на тип и все это в рантайме а затем в БД и там то-же скрипт и хочу отметить что таблица будет свежей и СУБД не проведет оптимизации таблицы + вывод и -> вся таблица в урну... уж лучше как по мне только java использовать тут хоть некоторая оптимизация будет в связи с повторяющимися циклами обработки...В любом  случае удачи!

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю все "прелести" при таком режиме работы с БД. Это просто один из вариантов обработки, чтобы не гонять в памяти большой объем. С радостью услышал бы какие ещё варианты могут быть

Comment: Можно загонять RAW данные сначала в NoSQL (MongoDB ..) и затем структурировать в SQL формат.

Comment: awk, join, sort и т.д.

Comment: Какая БД использоваться будет? Почему бы не воспользоваться встроенными возможностями БД. Например, в Oracle есть external tables, в PostgreSQL - foreign data (можно свой wrapper написать). И обращаться с файлами, как с обычными таблицами.

Comment: Не важно какая БД. Интересуют именно подходы к реализации. Существующие. External tables примерно дает тот же вариант, что описан в вопросе(Создание таблиц на основании файлов в реляционной модели). Но спасибо за вариант решения.

Comment: Будет хоть один оформленный ответ-то?)

Comment: А структуру файлов на основании чего вы определять хотите ? Ведь при любом решении SQL/NoSql/конечный автомат, вам надо в каком то виде систематизировать производимые изменения. Что, либо программа могла сама понять структуры и что с ними делать, либо что  бы можно было легко задать "что делать" . При текущей постановке я бы скорее всего решил бы обработать то что нужно на perl и не заморачиваться никакакими БД. И под конкретную ситуацию смог бы сделать оптимальный вариант по быстродействию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно записать файл построчно в таблицу, например c колонками DOC_NAME, ROW_NUMBER, ROW_CONTENT

в DOC_NAME - имя файла
в ROW_NUMBER - номер строки
в ROW_CONTENT - считываем строку из файла, например, Имя;Фамилия;Год_Рождения;Место_рождения - Петр;Семенов;12.12.1980;г. Москва

Далее это строчку можно распарсить с помощью sql по столбцам и вставить в заранее подготовленную таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO PARSED_TABLE1
SELECT           
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,0,INSTR(CON,CHR(59))-1)) NAME,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,1)+1,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)-
INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,1)-1)) SURNAME,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)+1,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,3)-
INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,2)-1)) BIRTHDAYDATE,    
TRIM(SUBSTR(CON,INSTR(CON,CHR(59),1,3)+1)) BIRTHPLACE  
FROM ( SELECT ROW_CONTENT CON FROM CONTENT_TABLE WHERE DOC_NAME="doc.csv")
```

По аналогии делаем запрос для заполнения PARSED_TABLE2, из 2-х таблиц склеиваешь новую как пожелаешь, можно сразу и без PARSED_TABLE склеивать.
CHR(59) - это символ ; в ANSII

Вот также хорошая статья на тему чтения из .csv в Oraсle БД http://torofimofu.blogspot.ru/2015/10/oracle-csv.html

Comment: Примерно так и сделали в итоге. Т.е. промежуточно грузим в БД и клеим SQL запросом на результат

Answer (score 0):

Все что вам нужно – [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html)

Пример использования взят [отсюда](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/Users/mkyong/csv/country.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] + "]");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

P.S. Боюсь, у меня недостаточно кармы чтобы ответить на ваши комментарии.

Comment: Если не затруднит, можете более обширно описать, как именно поможет использование набора классов данной билиотеки в моем вопросе? А именно, как можно одной лишь некой абстрактной "инструкцией" объединить два набора из различных файлов по некоторым критериям? Или выполнить группировочные операции 
 или операции поиска данных? И это, желательно, чтобы не надо было перекомпиливать код(т.к. мы ж помним, что данная библиотека - Java, верно?) Т.е. хотелось бы хранение таких вот "инструкций" в файле\БД или прочем....

Comment: + Вы, помоему, не тот пример скопировали от нашего заокеанского колеги)